# $f_1=\frac{x}{x+1}$ define $ f_n (x)=f_1 (f_{n-1}(x))$

Tags: calculus

Let$ f_1=\frac{x}{x+1}$ define $ f_n (x)=f_1 (f_{n-1}(x)) $where n $\ge $2. Then $f_n(x)$is

1. Decreasing in n

2 increasing in n

3 initially decreasing in n then increasing in n

4 initially increasing in n then decreasing in n

Comment: Yes$ fn=\frac{x}{nx+1}$ atleast if n=2,3. After that

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}&f_1(x)=\frac x{x+1}\\{}\\
&f_2(x)=\frac{\frac x{x+1}}{\frac x{x+1}+1}=\frac x{2x+1}\\{}\\
&f_3(x)=\frac{\frac x{2x+1}}{\frac x{2x+1}+1}=\frac x{3x+1}\\{}\\&\ldots\ldots\text{induction!}\ldots\ldots\\{}\\
&f_{n}(x):=f_x\left(f_{n-1}(x)\right)=f_1\left(\frac x{(n-1)x+1}\right)=\frac{\frac x{(n-1)x+1}}{\frac x{(n-1)x+1}+1}=\\{}\\&=\frac x{x+(n-1)x+1}=\frac x{nx+1}\end{align}$$

Well, now all is left is to check the given possibilites. Take it from here.